# Setting/finding Android 7 encryption password

Tags: 7.0-nougat, twrp, encryption, password

[With some hassle](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/196424/problems-installing-lineage-os-14-1-on-lenovo-p2-black-screen-blue-led) I updated the 2016 firmware on my Lenovo P2 to Android 7 (I think my carrier decided that their own app was more important than security updates).

Now that I wanted to put the TWRP recovery onto the phone instead of the stock one, I find out that the phone is encrypted, which it wasn't before. I have not asked for it (it appears Google does this by default now for Android 7) and I have never entered a password explicitly for encryption.

However, TWRP asks for a password for decryption purposes, I believe.

I use fingerprint/PIN as screen lock. [This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88845/how-to-change-encryption-password-android-5-0) and others suggest it should be the PIN, however while that works fine for a normal startup of the phone, that doesn't work in TWRP.

How would I find or set the right password to use (doubting there is a default password!)?

Comment: See https://android.stackexchange.com/a/230055

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there either is a bug in TWRP in that it won't accept a blank password (or that there is a default password in Android 7).

In either case, if I set the password under

```
Settings -> Security -> Screen lock -> [PIN] -> Password -> Require password to start device
```

(which I have never set before), then this password can be used in TWRP and must then also be used to unlock the phone instead of the PIN.

Comment: Sorry but that didn't work.

Comment: There’s also a default password, often even “default_password”, but some manufacturers use a different one or even a completely different mechanism, so that the above doesn’t work and TWRP cannot decrypt.